# How to update the position of snakes and ladders in an 2D array code?

Tags: java, 2d, 2d-games

```
  public class ChutesAndLadders2d {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   int[][] numbersOnBoard = new int [6][6];
    boardSetUpA (numbersOnBoard);
      printTwoD(numbersOnBoard);


}
public static void boardSetUpA (int[][]twoD) {
    //Square with even size

    //even rows
    for (int row = 0;row<twoD.length; row ++) {

        if (row %2 ==0) {
            int num = twoD.length*(twoD.length-row); 
            for (int col = 0; col<twoD[row].length; col ++ ) {
                twoD[row][col] = num;
                num--;
            }
        }//
        else {
            int num = twoD.length*(twoD.length-(row + 1))+ 1; 
            for (int col = 0; col<twoD[row].length; col ++ ) {
                twoD[row][col] = num;
                num++;
            }

        }
    }//for row

}//
       public static void printTwoD(int [][] array){
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++){
            System.out.print(array[row][column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
      }

      public static void boardDetails(String[][]board) {
         for (int row = 0;row<board.length; row++){
    for (int col = 0;col<board[row].length; col++){
        
        if( col+2 == row||col+1 == row*2 ){
            board[row][col] = "Lad"; // Append value 
        }
        else if (col*2 == row|| row*2 == col){
            board[row][col] = "Cht";// Append value 
        }
        else {
            board[row][col] = "    ";
        }
    }

    board[board.length-1][0] = "Start";
    if (board.length%2 ==0) {
        board[0][0] = "End";}
    else {
board[0][board.length-1]="End";
    }
    
}

        }
    public static void printBoard (int[][]twoD, String[][]strTwoD) {
     //Printing
      for (int row = 0;row<twoD.length;row++) {
    for (int col = 0;col<twoD[row].length;col++) {
        System.out.print(twoD[row][col] + " "+strTwoD[row][col]+"\t\t");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
   }

        }
```

This is the starter code I have for setting up the snakes and ladders game. I also tried to set the chutes/snakes and ladders on the board but it is not printing. How should I fix it and how do I develop this code to have three methods: update the moves of a player once he reaches a snake, a ladder, and once he rolls his die, from one place to another?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to implement a Shutes & Ladders game using a 2D `Array`? For sure! Does that make sense in an object-oriented language such as Java? I dont know ....

What do you need for that?

1. A square board with e.g. 36 playing fields.
2. Connections between two playing fields. (shutes and ladders)
3. Pawns and a dice.
4. A renderer that outputs the playing field (as text or graphics).
5. A program that allows input and connects everything to a functioning game.

Here is an example that works with a `List` instead of an `Array`. That can certainly be changed if it is necessary for your purposes.
I hope this is of some help to you.

P.S .: After the start, the board is displayed with field numbers. Shutes are shown as red lines. Ladders as green lines. Keys 1-6 on the keyboard simulate rolling the dice..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChutesAndLadders2d {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chutes and Ladders 2D");
        Game game = new ChutesAndLadders2d().new Game();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class Game extends JPanel{
        private final Font defaultFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16);
        private final BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(4f);
        private static final int SCALE = 64;

        // board and pawns
        private final Board board = new Board(6);
        private final List<Pawn> pawns = new ArrayList<>();

        public Game(){
            setFocusable(true);     // receive Keyboard-Events
            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { 
                    char c = e.getKeyChar();
                    if(c >= '1' && c <= '6'){
                        int steps = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c));
                        Pawn pawn = pawns.get(0);
                        pawn.move(steps);
                        Field field = board.get(pawn.fieldIndex);
                        if(field.targetKind() != Kind.NONE){
                            pawn.move(field.getTarget().index - field.index);
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
            board.connect(5, 12);   // Ladder  5 -> 12
            board.connect(8, 4);    // Shute   8 -> 4
            board.connect(15, 32);  // Ladder  15 -> 32
            board.connect(35, 17);  // Shute   35 -> 17
            board.connect(23, 30);  // Ladder   23 -> 30
            pawns.add(new Pawn(Color.BLUE, board.size() - 1));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            setFont(defaultFont);
            for(Field field : board){
                Point p = field.getLocation();
                g2d.drawRect(p.x * SCALE, p.y * SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);
                g2d.drawString(field.text, p.x * SCALE + 24, p.y * SCALE + 40);
            }
            for(Field field : board){
                if(field.targetKind() != Kind.NONE){
                    g2d.setColor(field.targetKind() == Kind.LADDER ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
                    g2d.setStroke(stroke);
                    Point source = field.getLocation();
                    Point target = field.getTarget().getLocation();
                    g2d.drawLine(source.x * SCALE + 40, source.y * SCALE + 24, target.x * SCALE + 40, target.y * SCALE + 24);
                }
            }
            for(Pawn pawn : pawns){
                Point loc = board.get(pawn.fieldIndex).getLocation();
                g2d.setColor(pawn.color);
                g2d.fillOval(loc.x * SCALE + 32, loc.y * SCALE + 32, 16, 16);
            }
        }
    }

    class Board implements Iterable<Field>{
        private final List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();

        public Board(int size){
            for(int index = 0; index < size * size; index++)
                fields.add(new Field(index, size));
        }

        public Field get(int index){
            return fields.get(index);
        }

        public void connect(int startFieldnumber, int targetFieldnumber){
            get(startFieldnumber - 1).setTarget(get(targetFieldnumber - 1));
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<Field> iterator() {
            return fields.iterator();
        }

        public int size(){
            return fields.size();
        }
    }

    class Field{ 
        final int index;
        final String text;
        final int size;
        private Field target;

        public Field(int index, int size){
            this.index = index;
            this.size = size;
            text = "" + (index + 1);
        }

        public void setTarget(Field target){
            if(target == this) return;
            this.target = target;
        }

        public Field getTarget(){
            return target;
        }

        public Kind targetKind(){
            if(target == null) return Kind.NONE;
            return index < target.index ? Kind.LADDER : Kind.SHUTE;
        }

        public Point getLocation(){
            int x = index % size;
            int y = index / size;
            if(y % 2 != 0) x = size - x - 1;
            return new Point(x, size - y - 1);
        }
    }

    class Pawn{
        int fieldIndex = 0;
        int maxIndex;
        Color color;

        public Pawn(Color color, int maxIndex){
            this.color = color;
            this.maxIndex = maxIndex;
        }

        public void move(int steps){
            fieldIndex += steps;
            if(fieldIndex < 0) fieldIndex = 0;
            if(fieldIndex > maxIndex) fieldIndex = maxIndex;
        }
    }

    enum Kind{
        NONE, SHUTE, LADDER
    }
}
```